# MERN stack : Express api returning empty data , but the data is already present in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, express, mern

I am new to the MERN stack, and I have been trying to access my collections in MongoDB.
Here is the code for the router, view bookings:

```js
/*This is router file*/
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const express = require('express');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    let book = require('../models/BookTravel');
    const router = require('express').Router()
    
    router.use(express.json())
    
    router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
      
          // Company.aggregate({companyId})
          book.find()
            .then((result) => {
              console.log(result)
              return res.status(200).json(result)
            })
            
        
      })
    
    module.exports = router;
```

```js
    /*
     * this is for model
    */
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    
    const TravelSchema = new Schema({
     firstname:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    
     bookingId:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    
    },
    
     lastname:{
    
        type: String,
        required: true
    
    },
     startcity:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    
    }
    })
        const travel = mongoose.model('travel', TravelSchema)
    

        module.exports = travel;
```

```js
////in app.js file
 

       const viewBookings = require('./routes/viewBookings');
        app.use('/viewBookings', viewBookings)
```

The postman is also giving empty result.

What am I missing out ? Is it not possible to access the already existing collection with this method ?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some code in the router file.
for example! If you want to get data from a database

you can simply use like below this

```js
.......

router.get("/",async (req,res)=>
{
   try{
   const result = await book.find();
   res.status(200).json({"message" : result})
 }
catch(error)
{ 
  console.log(error)
}
})

......
```